# httpd (apache) - rewrite page -> query parameter

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf, query-string

I have a website containing a directory and pages.
Let's call the directory 'Maintenance' and pages 'page1.html,...'

I want to redirect each file under the directory to query parameter such as '/?q=pageX'.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName      myServer.com
ServerAlias     www.myServer.com
DocumentRoot    "/var/www/html"    

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]

RewriteRule ^(/Maintenance/[^/]+)\.html$ /?q=MyPage [R=301,L]

RewriteRule "^(.*)\.ht$" "index.html/?q=$1 [NC,L,QSA,CO=RewriteRule;01;https://www.myServer.com;30/;SameSite=None;Secure]"
Redirect permanent /(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1
```

---

I've been trying ModeRewrite w/ various setups, read lots of 'how to' but nothing works for me.

Help will be most appreciated.

Thanks,
John

Comment: Could you please share your htaccess file in your question along with samples/examples of URLs for better understanding of question thank you

Comment: .htaccess fragment added.

Thanks Ravinder.

Comment: Ravinder,

Thanks for your recommendations - I'll do so.

As far as your answer is concerned, unfortunately, it's not working.
Regardless, thanks for your time and effort.

Comment: Could you please do mention in my answer's comments what's not working and what errors are you getting, lets talk there and see if we can fix it :)

Comment: What is purpose of `Redirect permanent /(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1` rule?

Comment: anubhava - I was experimenting with various setups prior to encountering the above problem. Purpose: switching from http to https

Comment: `I want to redirect each file under the directory to query parameter such as '/?q=pageX'.`: Do you want to do this for only `/Maintenance` directory or for any request that is not a file and not a directory? Better to add few more examples

Comment: http -> https : obviously, for all files.

Comment: Are you using these rules in .htaccess or in vhost confg as shown in question?

Comment: In the vhost, as above

Answer (score 1):

You can use these rules in 2 `VirtualHost` sections:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName      myServer.com
ServerAlias     www.myServer.com
DocumentRoot    "/var/www/html"

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName      myServer.com
ServerAlias     www.myServer.com
DocumentRoot    "/var/www/html"

RewriteRule ^/Maintenance/([^/]+)\.html?$ /?q=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)\.ht$ /?q=$1 [NC,L,QSA,CO=RewriteRule;01;https://www.myServer.com;30/;SameSite=None;Secure]
</VirtualHost>
```

It is important to keep rewrite rules in `VirtualHost *:443` because port 80 one is just redirecting all the traffic to `https`.

Comment: anubhava - thanks.
Nice setup.

1. Switching from HTTP to HTTPS w/ 301  =>  OK

2. Under "Maintenance" there are a couple of pages, say 
PageMaintenance1.htm, PageMaintenance2.htm, ...
When a robot looks at them, they all should point to 'meServer.com/?q=MyPage' (global)

RewriteRule ^(/Maintenance/[^/]+)\.html$ /?q=MyPage [QSA,NC,L] 
-> it does not switch to meServer.com/?q=MyPage

Many thanks for your answer.

Comment: If you want that URL to change then use: `RewriteRule ^(/Maintenance/[^/]+)\.html$ /?q=MyPage [QSA,NC,L,R=301]`

Comment: Not working. Reason: no switching occurs but the page is scanned. More info: this is an SEO issue, related to robots. I'd like to simplify it if you don't mind. Let's say: /Maintenance/pageX.html should lead to https://server.com/?q=pageX.  IF my understanding is correct, this is actually what is supposed to happen: if a robot scans https://server.com/Maintenance.pageX.html it should permanently switch [R=301] to https://server.com/?q=pageX and a robot should view/scan the /?q=pageX combo BUT never pageX.html by itself. Many thanks for your efforts anubhava

Comment: I have made a minor update. However if I understand you completely you want to serve a different content to search bots and different one to real users. Please read more why it is not a good idea: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/guidelines/cloaking?hl=en&visit_id=637484500226478563-3661610461&rd=1

Comment: btw you never mentioned SEO and robot etc in your question

Comment: Thanks for the info. This is not clocking as THE SAME page is served to the robot and user. It's simply a redirection, telling the robot not to scan the page but access the index.html first and after that 'view' it.  As far as Google is concerned, according to our tests, there is no problem, excepting the fact that the robot perceives it as a duplicate (obviously, same content in two places: once by itself, once under the index), hence the need for a redirect. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Even a redirection if that is only done for search bot will be categorized as cloaking.

Comment: Well, I suppose this is a debatable point as it will render invalid the dynamic loading of any page.  What I was referring to is known as 'white cloaking'. More info: https://moz.com/blog/white-hat-cloaking-it-exists-its-permitted-its-useful

Comment: First of all you should ask all this in question not in comments section. There is a separate forum for webmaster that deals with SEO issues. I understand *dynamic loading of any page* very well and have done that on several live websites but never used any rule that redirects differently for normal users and search bots.

Comment: You have me thinking :)  The SEO issue - I wasn't aware. Thanks
Let's consider this:
- Robot finds pageX.html 
- Upon accessing it, Apache said: DO NOT read it but go here (/?q=pageX), hence no contents are to be seen by the robot because of the redirect (R=301), so no cloaking can occur
- server.com/?q=pageX loads (index + pageX)
- contents views once.
So, regardless of how a search engine might perceive it (cloaking/not cloaking), the redirect MUSt take place BEFORE the search engine will decide if it is cloaking or not.
is this your understanding as well ? .

Comment: Yes that is very well my understanding as wel

Comment: OK, so we are in agreement. Interestingly enough, we also tested a "RedirectMatch 301". Working well, excepting the fact that the (index + pageX) is loaded twice. So, with "RedirectMatch" we get twice what we want, with "RewriteRule" we get pageX only (no redirect). We are confused. Anyway, thank you very much for all your efforts. Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Based on your shown samples, could you please try following. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^Maintenance ?q=pageX [NC,L]
```